# Grouping numeric values

Tags: r

I have a numeric variable `Tot_cd` that goes from 1 to 50.
I would like to create a copy of that variable (`tcd_grp`) that groups some of the numbers but leaves 1 and 2 alone  e.g. 1, 2, 3 to 5, 6 or more

based on a similar answer I tried using `cut` as follows:

```
tcd_grp <- (Tot_cd)
cut(tcd_grp, c(-Inf,1,2,5,Inf), labels =c("1","2","3-5","6 or more"))
```

this seemed not to work as the frequencies for `Tcd_grp` were the same as for `Tot_cd`

Comment: Or it could be typo  `lables`

Comment: If you take input as `x <- 1:10` and then do `cut(x, c(-Inf,1,2,5,Inf), labels =c("1","2","3-5","6 or more"))` the code seems to be working. What output do you get? Can you share your data and make this post [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) so that we can understand the actual issue you are facing.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share my data.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share my data.  When I run:   x <- 1:10
cut(x,c(-Inf,1,2,5,Inf), labels=c("1","2","3-5","6 or more")) : I get the following output:  [1] 1         2         3-5       3-5       3-5       6 or more 6 or more 6 or more 6 or more 6 or more.  The labels seem to be tracking the values of x. but when I ask for a frequency distribution the grouping disappears.                                 
 table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

Answer (score 1):

Question:I have a numeric variable Tot_cd that goes from 1 to 50. I would like to create a copy of that variable (tcd_grp) that groups some of the numbers but leaves 1 and 2 alone e.g. 1, 2, 3 to 5, 6 or more

Solution: First I needed to load the expss package
Then the following SPSS like code solved my problem

tcd_grp<-(TCD)
recode(tcd_grp, 1 ~ copy, 2:4 ~ 2, 5%thru%hi ~ 5) %into% r_tcd_grp
val_lab(r_tcd_grp)=c("1" = 1, "2 to 4" = 2, "5 or more" =5)